# Collapse a data.frame into a vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
COL1  COL2  COL3 

   a           h
   b     f    
   c     g       
   d           j
```

I would like the following output:

```
 COL  
   a    
   b    
   c    
   d   
   f   
   g   
   h   
   j
```

How this can be done? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your `data.frame` is named `dat`, try:

```
unlist(dat, use.names=FALSE)
```

You may also want to try the following:

```
as.character(unlist(dat, use.names=FALSE))
c(na.omit(as.character(unlist(dat, use.names=FALSE))))
```

which might be useful if your data are entered as factors.

Also, in your question, you make it appear that you don't actually have a basic "vector", but rather a one-column `data.frame`. Thus, something like `dat2 <- data.frame(COL = c(na.omit(as.character(unlist(dat, use.names=FALSE)))))` might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

```
do.call(c, your_data_frame)
```

An example:

```
> dat <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 2:4)
> do.call(c, dat)
a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 
 1  2  3  2  3  4
```

This takes each column of the data.frame and treats it as a separate input into c so you're just concatenating everything into a single vector.

Comment: Hi Dason. Thanks first of all. I tried, but the following error occurs: Error in do.call(c, dat) : 
  'what' must be a character string or a function

Comment: @Bnf8, sounds like you've used `c` as a variable name somewhere. Try `do.call(base::c, your_data_frame)`.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Good call.  And good job spotting the duplicate.

Comment: @Dason: Finding it was easy.  A simple search for "[r] collapse column".

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Easy or not - it was still a good call looking for it.  I probably should more in the habit of searching for possible duplicates.

Comment: @dason - nah, where would the easy rep come from then?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `unlist`:

```
dat <- data.frame(A1 = letters[1:3],
                  A2 = letters[2:4],
                  A3 = c("f", "a", "b"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

unlist(dat)

# A11 A12 A13 A21 A22 A23 A31 A32 A33 
# "a" "b" "c" "b" "c" "d" "f" "a" "b"
```